# Why does my connection keep getting aborted?

Tags: mysql, azure

I was trying to connect to MySQL server 8.0 from azure but every time I do I get the error

> "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.)".

I enabled TCP/IP and Shared Memory and checked to make sure that the port had a inbound rule for the firewall that allows it to be accessed but I keep getting the same error. I haven't touched the advanced setting though. Any help would be appreciated, thank you [What I am inputting in azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv3Ah.png)
[image]

Comment: "microsoft sql server" is a totally different thing than "mysql server"

Comment: Thank You! Sorry, if that was a dumb question, I've never used Azure before so I was following tutorials on youtube and completely missed that.

Comment: not a dumb question at all

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mysql for azure services ? Then there is setting allow for all azure resources. And also check the firewall setting for this.